# How do I specifically use an NPM local dependency for local development and one from an external registry for production?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am working on a suite of tools that all use code from the same library. The library is also developed in-house.

When I publish a tool, I want it to use a specific version of the library from the NPM registry (npmjs.com) but when I develop it locally, I want it to specifically use a relative local package (i.e.: `../some_package`). It seems like I can do this with different environment variables and `scripts` in `package.json` but that seems very roundabout.

The part that matters in one of these tools looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@teaminkling/autolib": "^0.1.1"
},
```

...which is fine and works for production. However, to work on it locally and still have version control, I've needed to do this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@teaminkling/autolib": "file:../autolib"
},
```

I would expect this question be a duplicate since I think it's a pretty common development pattern, but I couldn't find anything after a while. I also welcome comments about better ways to handle this kind of library-dependency management.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run `npm link` inside the `autolib` source, then run `npm link @teaminkling/autolib` in any package source that you want to use the development version with. Your `package.json` should still refer to the real versions for production, but they will be ignored for locally linked packages.

Comment: Amazing, thanks! That concludes an hour of searching. I'm attributing it to a case of the Mondays.